# Check a user's input is correctly formatted

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I'm trying to validate a user's input when they enter a date into my bash script.

The correct format should be YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS

What I have so far is this, but it's not quite right.

```
read -p "-" datetime
if [[ $datetime ! "*[^2000-2100]-[^01-12]-[^10-31] [^00-24]:[^00-60]:[^00-60]*" ]]
  then
    echo "Not a date"
fi
```

Comment: Hmmm... `2100-02-31 24:60:60` doesn't sound like a valid date/time to me... Even if the regex matching did work that way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could say:

```
if ! date -d "$datetime" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
  echo "Not a date"
fi
```

---

Using regexp isn't really recommended, but if you insist you could say:

```
if [[ "$datetime" != 2[0-1][0-9][0-9]-[0-1][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]\ [0-2][0-9]:[0-6][0-9]:[0-6][0-9] ]]; then
  then
    echo "Not a date"
fi
```

Comment: @Steve Yes, better to use `date` rather than using regexp to parse date.

Comment: You know, this is crazy clever, because you can put it anything like "2 weeks friday 10pm" and it understands it.

Comment: @Steve Yup, it'll essentially validate everything that's considered good by `date`.

Comment: Yeah tried that, says it's more complex than they can easily list on the man page.

Comment: Wouldn't the regexp accept e.g. "2013-19-39 29:69:69" as valid ?

Comment: @MikeD Doesn't the answer mention that using regexps isn't recommended?

Comment: hmmm ... I'd say it's not only not recommended, it's just not serving the purpose at all - while the 1st variant is 100% spot on

Comment: @MikeD I guess it wasn't obvious -- the objective of posting the regex version was an attempt to demonstrate the problem with the way OP was trying to use the regex.