# Validating user fed time in bash with regex pattern

Tags: regex, bash, shell, time-format

Assume a user fed time :

```
read -p "Enter the start time you want to start(hh:mm:ss) " user_start_time
```

and the regex :

```
timePattern="[0-2][0-3]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]"
```

if i do :

```
if [ "$user_start_time" == "$timePattern" ] 
#or if [ "$user_start_time" =~ "$timePattern" ]
then
         echo "in if"
else
         echo "in else"
fi
```

It doesn't validates.....being newbie, i understand comparison of `int` or `string` but how we go about `time` (*date is there too, but `date -d` solves lot of problems*)

[There is this question too](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43371/time-validation-with-regex)  but couldn't understand the accepted answer!!

Comment: Your problem is using `==` and `=~` within `[ ... ]`.  You need to use double square brackets.  Refer to the linked question.

Comment: @devnull : yeah, referred it the moment u posted....thankx mate!! :)

Comment: @devnull : a quick question, will it be a good practice if i always use `[[` in validations rather than `[` just to be on safer side??

Comment: Moreover, avoid regex for validating date/time.  You might want to refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20326011/2235132) answer for an alternate approach.

Comment: You can, it's just that `[[` isn't as portable!  If you're sure where your script would be running, I see no harm.

Comment: @devnull : i already visited your above url but problem is that i may have a custom time format, so m not at liberty to use standard methods...thats why i see `regex` as my only option!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For regex matching you need to use `=~` operator instead of `==` in BASH. So use it like this:

```
[[ "$user_start_time" =~ $timePattern ]] && echo "in if" || echo "in else"
```

Also you need to remove quotes around regex variable `$timePattern`

Comment: +1 : so my code has 2 mistakes....`Pattern should not be in quotes` and `double square brackets` ....mmm.....when should the double square brackets and single square brackets be used?? i mean is there any criteria for it???

Comment: As a thumb rule always used `[[ and ]]` while using BASH. As you have noticed `[ and ]` don't even support `=~` operator. `[` was actually a command which is still supported for backward compatibility purpose but for all practical purposes in BASH use `[[ and ]]` as it is much more feature rich and efficient.

Comment: didn't this thing...thanks!! :)

Comment: @MortezaLSC: Yes sure you can do: `if [[ "$user_start_time" =~ $timePattern ]]; then echo "in if"; else echo "in else"; fi`

Comment: I removed my comment... I found it yes thank you :)